# AD. Можно ли обычному пользователю из одного домена получить доступ в другой домен?

Tags: active-directory

Я установил на компьютер Windows Server 2016, установил AD DS, DNS Server, WEB Server. Подключил свой домен контроллер к уже существующем лесу. В этом лесу есть ещё домен с пользователями и мне надо, чтобы эти пользователи имели доступ к моему домену и с правами администратора на моём домене. Это реально?
Расскажу более подробно. На моём новом компе, куда я установил Windows Server установлено WEB приложение. Вход туда происходит через windows authentication. Поэтому надо чтобы юзеры с другого домена могли подключаться к моему приложению, которое находится в другом домене. Моё приложение будет видеть их? мне надо будет указать приложению их домен, где будет проверяться к какой группе принадлежит юзер.

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать один домен общий?

Comment: Дело в том, что если я подключаюсь к тому существующему домену, то на моём сервере нету группы administrators. А мне надо дать одной проге именно такие права, без этих прав приложение моё не может её запустить. Моё приложение запускает эту прогу и я заметил, что если юзер состоит в группе Administrators, то всё работает. Потому что в том домене уже стоит моё web приложение и всё ок. Но тогда надо юзеру давать права админа, а они не хотят. в реале уже будет доменная сеть и они поставят к себе на комп сервер и моё приложение. Поэтому я подумал что мне надо может тогда создать дочерний домен?

Comment: Так какие права дать на локальной машине решает как бы администратор домена. Это одна из его ключевых функций. Даст Вам Administration, будет administration :)

Comment: Вы не поняли меня мне кажется. пользователи, которые уже существуют в том домене не имеют админских прав. но чтобы работало моё приложение, а они логинятся в него они должны иметь админские права, чтобы приложение могло запускать внешние программы. Поэтому я хотел запускать приложение в отдельном домене и чтобы эти пользователи имели там админские права. как-то так.

Comment: Ваше приложение что такого делает, что нужны права администратора у залогиненного пользователя?  Для того, чтобы приложение могло запускать другие приложения с правами администратора - не обязательно, чтобы у пользователя который в него логинится были такие права. Главное, чтобы были права у приложения, а политику запуска/не запуска решает в данном случае само приложение. Например, можно создать отдельную группу в домене... И предоставлять доступ к некоторым функциям по ней...

Comment: Да. я Сам удивился почему так странно у меня работает. Может я что-то не так понимаю. У меня PHP приложение. я в IIS пулу приложений дал права Network Service - не помогало. тогда я дал права админские юзерам и всё пошло. у меня PHP приложение вызывает cmd.exe. Изначально ваще ругалось типа unable to fork... ещё у меня вызывается git.exe тот тоже ругается. Хотя локально запускаешь - всё ок. с другого компа - ж.опа.

Comment: с другого компа  токо git.exe почему-то выдаёт ошибку. В конце клонирования. я думаю это потому что не хватает прав. локально же всё ок. я захожу локально под доменным пользователем Bart - всё ок. захожу с другого компа в приложение под тем же логином и ошибку git выдаёт в конце.

Comment: Ещё у меня через cmd.exe запускается schtsks.exe если Git ещё что-то делает и потом валится, то schtasks ваще ничего не говорит и тупо ничего не делает. Помню юзеров прописал в группу Administrators и всё пошло. понимаю что неправильно, но не знаю какое решение сделать. Не понимаю почему доменные юзеры должны иметь права  хотя приложение работает в пуле. Там я тоже прописал как Administrator, чтобы всё заработало. Я совсем запутался.